# How to clean Apache Ignite caches and sort of start over?

Tags: ignite

I have a 3 node ignite cluster and 1 client that creates cache. During the development and testing, I had to stop the cluster or interrupt the cache building several time and the entire system is broken now. Only one node starts and the other nodes crashes. The client is blocked and it does not do anythin.

Is there any way to clean everything and sort of start fresh?
I am using Ignite 2.1 and using Persistent Cache storage.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Just delete Ignite work directory - by default, it's ${IGNITE_HOME}/work.

Also, if you configured WAL store path, you need to clean it too:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store#section-write-ahead-log

**Note: All data in persistent store will be lost.**

Comment: Evgenii, I have my code compiled into a single executable Jar. The location of my jar is /home/user/ignite-app.jar. I simply execute this jar from a command line as java -jar ignite-app.jar. I did not have to set IGNITE_HOME environment variable. In this case I do not see the work directory anywhere. I did not explicitly set the WAL path. Could you please tell me where I would find the work directory in this case? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: as it said in doc: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#getWorkDirectory()
If IGNITE_HOME is not provided, then system temp directory is used.
You need to find work dir in your system temp dir.

Comment: Evgenii, Thank you so much for your help. I deleted the work directory from the tmp dir and restarted the ignite cluster. Everything worked fine. Thank you so much.